.NET MAUI intuitive context menu for ListView items
I have a .NET MAUI App with a ListView Control.
Every ListViewItem opens a new Details Page when being selected (let-click/tapped).
Additionally, I have a set of actions (Edit, Delete, Add Child ...) that could be performed for each ListViewItem. I want these Actions to be intuitively arranged in some kind of context menu that is easy to use on all platforms:

Clicking a "Hamburger" button (that is part of the ListViewItem) should open it
Right-Clicking the ListViewItem on Windows should open it
Long-Pressing the ListViewItem on iOS & Android should open it (while not disabling default selection of the ListViewItem)

To illustrate my vision: the context menu of Spotify Songs in a Playlist would be a positive example
I experimented with all kinds of "Out of the box" MAUI Solutions, but nothing seems to check all my boxes. This does not seem like such an explicit requirement to me - Is there an easy way to integrate this context menu for ListViewItems?
The closest I have been is with <ViewCell.ContextActions>, but it seems they can not be shown by the click of a button.

Yes, we usually use the menu items for ListView item context menus. And that's what it's currently designed to do.

Are you using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview?view=net-maui-8.0 for your context menus? if so you can use the Open and Close methods for point 3, not sure what you can do for the rest though
